# application Finder delete folders together

Tags: applescript

Below is my code:

```
 set sourceFolder1 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL_mixer.framework"

set sourceFolder2 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL_ttf.framework"

set sourceFolder3 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL_image.framework"



set folderList to {sourceFolder1, sourceFolder2}

tell application "Finder"

repeat with thisFolder in folderList

    if exists folder thisFolder then

        delete folder thisFolder
    end if

end repeat


end tell
```

The problem with this code is: I have to give password for every framework I want to delete (to the trash folder), Is there a way to give the password only once for all deleting work?

I cannot use shell script with rm (because rm will move files to the trash folder, but without put back option).

I notice that when the frameworks are deleted, it says delete 1 item. But when I use Finder to delete multiple files, it says delete N items. How can I implement the same thing, instead of delete 1 item each time in my code, delete N items at once, of course give password only once as well. Thanks a lot.

LJ

Comment: You can use shelf and sudo to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "Finder" to delete {sourceFolder1, sourceFolder2, sourceFolder3}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This is exactly what I need.  By the way, is it possible to explain a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to check if folders exist, then reveal all existing folders and delete them? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this was nonsense. Just putting the folders in a list should do the trick.

Comment: If a folder in the selection does not exist, then delete selection will fail. So I think it is necessary to check if a folder exists. What is your opinion? Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, yes, put the folders in the list, it does the work as long as all folders exist.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you for all responses.

It is based on the code given by user309603, a little modification has been done.

```
set sourceFolder1 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL_mixer.framework"

set sourceFolder2 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL_ttf.framework"

set sourceFolder3 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDLimage.framework"


set list1 to {}


tell application "Finder"
activate

if exists folder sourceFolder1 then
    set list1 to {sourceFolder1}
end if

if exists folder sourceFolder2 then
    set list1 to list1 & sourceFolder2
end if

if exists folder sourceFolder3 then
    set list1 to list1 & sourceFolder3
end if


delete list1    

end tell
```

Thanks again for all the help!